# Java Client Threadpool Full

Tags: java

We are Running into this problem which says Client thread pool is full. Is there a limit on the number of threads created on the client JVM

```
2012-11-12 10:09:54,206 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.splwg.oms.client.util.ClientThreadPool:  The client thread pool is full
java.lang.Exception: Stack Trace:
                at com.splwg.oms.client.util.ClientThreadPool.dumpExtendedStack(ClientThreadPool.java:49)
                at com.splwg.oms.client.util.ClientThreadPool$MyRejectedHandler.rejectedExecution(ClientThreadPool.java:169)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.adapter.JBotAdapter.processCommands(JBotAdapter.java:652)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.adapter.JBotAdapter.processEvent(JBotAdapter.java:591)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.listener.JTableAdapterListener.valueChanged(JTableAdapterListener.java:106)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.listener.JTableAdapterListener.selected(JTableAdapterListener.java:41)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.component.JBotTable.fireJBotSelection(JBotTable.java:376)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.component.JBotTable.changeSelection(JBotTable.java:240)
                at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseDragged(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Unknown Source)
                at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2012-11-12 10:09:54,206 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.splwg.oms.jbot.adapter.JDialogAdapter:  eventID = SelectPerform
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
                at com.splwg.oms.client.util.ClientThreadPool$MyRejectedHandler.rejectedExecution(ClientThreadPool.java:170)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.adapter.JBotAdapter.processCommands(JBotAdapter.java:652)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.adapter.JBotAdapter.processEvent(JBotAdapter.java:591)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.listener.JTableAdapterListener.valueChanged(JTableAdapterListener.java:106)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.listener.JTableAdapterListener.selected(JTableAdapterListener.java:41)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.component.JBotTable.fireJBotSelection(JBotTable.java:376)
                at com.splwg.oms.jbot.component.JBotTable.changeSelection(JBotTable.java:240)
                at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseDragged(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Unknown Source)
                at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: We'll probably need to be able to see the code for `com.splwg.oms.client.util.ClientThreadPool` to help with this.

Answer (score 2):

This means your thread pool cannot complete the tasks as fast as they are added - the queue keeps growing until you run out of space.
Solutions:

- more threads (there is a limit past which you will not have any improvement)
- larger or unlimited queue (partial solution, will only delay the problem)
- smaller tasks (your best bet)

Comment: I Do not have access to the source code(we get only the binaries from the vendor). Could this be due to the threads not being closed in the code once work was complete?

Comment: You should not close threads - threads are managed and reused where possible (which gives you a performance boost). However, your tasks must terminate at a certain point (calling implicitly or explicitly return). It could be your tasks try to take care of their own lifecycle, enclosing their code in a while(true){} loop (or similar)